# Update panel send all the page to the server

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, updatepanel, ascx

Good morning everyone, I have a page with a section on the left (an ascx control) with an updatepanel and on the right the remaining part of the page.
The update panel here works pretty well and I am happy for its job.

However in another page I have the same ascx control on the left and tens of pictures on the right.When I use here the dropdown on the left menu (contained in the updatepanel), before to receive serverside the command takes a lot of time and by my opinion is due the browser is uploading all the info (pictures,.. in general the whole page ) again to the server.

Is it possible this my assumption, I haven't found advice on internet and I have a big problem of performance.

Just to highlight one thing the update panel is working , I am correctly updating only the update panel without a full postback, the problem is during the server call that takes time ....

Kind Regards,

luca

Comment: I think some code would probably help here, can you edit your post to include some relevant parts of your application? Your comment about pictures being uploaded seems strange - are the pictures you mention something that the user is uploading from their own computer, or images that you're providing on the page? If it's the latter, they shouldn't be getting uploaded, should they?

Comment: Thanks for you fast response, yes are pictures I am showing into the page.   It's hard post some code, but here I can give you an example . try the menu on the left with make/model/year selection from the home page,   http://www.tpmseuroshop.com and the same from here  http://www.tpmseuroshop.com/2015/alfa-romeo/4c-[4c].html  , if you have a slow connection you feel the difference...

Comment: Post your User Control markup